# Multiselection parameter for picklist datatype soql

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, multi-select

In my vf page the date is presented based on only one value of the status picklist for the opportunists object.

Now i need to extend my search criteria in such as way that rather than selecting only one stagename, i need to pass multi select picklist value to query such that it can select any multi value  from front end to soql query

I tried passing  the stagename fields is only picklist and even i try to pass a multi select value to query i

Vf Page

```
<apex:page controller="Pagination_min">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:selectList value="{!shiftType}" multiselect="false" size="1" 
                       label="Shift Types" title="Users" onchange="show()" >
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Won" itemLabel="Closed Won"/>                
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Lost" itemLabel="Closed lost"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Needs Analysis" itemLabel="need"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Qualification" itemLabel="Qualification"/>
      </apex:selectList>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a">
              <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!a.closeDate}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!a.stageName}"/>                   
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
          <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
              <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="|<" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
              <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
              <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
              <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">|" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
              <apex:outputText >{!(setCon.pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((setCon.pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(setCon.pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
              <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}" title="Refresh Page"/>
              <apex:actionFunction name="show" action="{!refresh}" reRender="pb" />
              <apex:selectList value="{!size}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="show()">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                 </apex:selectList>     
              <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                  <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText=""/>
              </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:panelGrid>
          <apex:actionFunction name="show" action="{!refresh}" reRender="pb" />
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

```
public with sharing class Pagination_min {

  public String shiftType { get; set; }    
  Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
  Public Integer size{get;set;}
  public boolean test = false;
  public       Pagination_min() {
     shiftType='Closed Won';
     refresh();
  }
  public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
   get{
     if(setCon == null){
       if(test == false){
         size = 10;
       }
       string queryString = 'Select Name, closeDate, stageName 
        from Opportunity where stageName =:shiftType order by Name';
       setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
       setCon.setPageSize(size);
       noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
       test = true;
     }
     return setCon;
    }set;
  }

 Public List<Opportunity> getAccounts(){
   List<Opportunity> accList = new List<Opportunity>();
   for(Opportunity a : (List<Opportunity>)setCon.getRecords())
     accList.add(a);
   return accList;
 }

public pageReference refresh() {
   setCon = null;
   getAccounts();
   setCon.setPageNumber(1);
   return null;
}
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
  options.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('20','20'));
  options.add(new SelectOption('30','30'));
  return options;
}
  }
```

Comment: (1) please strip out portions of the apex code and vf page not relevant to the question (like the pagination); (2) define what is not working and the results you are getting

Comment: I can change the vf code as required. but for apex code, the query is fetched using standard controller , and cant remove it.  The code is a simple pickilist value search from Vf to apex and the returned query is paginated using standard set controller. Here only we have only picklist value to be search at a time like only "Closed Won" the all the records will be of Closed Won status only, and "Closed Lost" will give you records based on Closed lost status only. i am trying to select both from vf like a multipicklist which should bring me both the status records in one go.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

The VF page selectList:

```
   <apex:selectList value="{!shiftType}" multiselect="false" size="1" 
                   label="Shift Types" title="Users" onchange="show()" >
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Won" itemLabel="Closed Won"/>                
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Lost" itemLabel="Closed lost"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Needs Analysis" itemLabel="need"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Qualification" itemLabel="Qualification"/>
  </apex:selectList>
```

is defined as `multiSelect="false"`. If you want multiple values to be selected by the user, then this attribute needs to be `true`

The value transmitted to the VF controller property as a setter shiftType will be a string delimited by semi-colons of the selected item(s)

The SOQL query:

```
string queryString = 'Select Name, closeDate, stageName 
    from Opportunity where stageName =:shiftType order by Name';
```

will not work as is for multi-select values. As Stagename is not a MultiSelect field, you can't use the `includes` SOQL operator. Instead, you will use the `IN` operator and convert the user-selected MSP to a list as in:

```
string[] selectedShiftTypeList = this.shiftType.split(';');
string queryString = 'Select Name, closeDate, stageName 
    from Opportunity where stageName IN :selectedShiftTypeList order by Name';
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is because in your

```
string queryString = 'Select Name, closeDate, stageName 
        from Opportunity where stageName =:shiftType order by Name';
```

you are binding stage name with **string** datatype although you want multiselect picklist possible values.

so, instead of String shiftType you use **Set** shiftType and make slight changes in your query

```
string queryString = 'Select Name, closeDate, stageName 
    from Opportunity where stageName IN :shiftType order by Name';
```